# VBA - get range using Dim values - range of object __global failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Dims

```
Dim PlayersStartAt As Integer
Dim PlayersEndAt As Integer

PlayersStartAt = 101
PlayersEndAt = PlayersStartAt + 50


Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B & PlayersStartAt:B & PlayersEndAt"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

and want to execute the following line of code.

It with great with `Range("B101:B151")`;

What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
Range("B & PlayersStartAt:B & PlayersEndAt")
```

to

```
Range("B" & PlayersStartAt & ":B" & PlayersEndAt)
```

`PlayersStartAt` and `PlayersEndAt` are variables. Anything that you put between quotes will be taken as a string :)